# How much does a query of deletion costs in terms of operations when the attribute is a key or an attribute?

Tags: performance, heap, query-performance

How much does the following query costs in terms of operations when the attribute is a **key** or an **attribute** ?

```
DELETE
  FROM R
    WHERE ATTRIBUTE = 50
```

We assume we have R(K,A,B,other) a relation with

- N<sub>rec</sub>(R)=100000,
- L<sub>r</sub>=100 byte I think the size of these records...
- K, a key in    [1;100000]

  - *A with integer values uniformly distributed in the range (1,1000)*

R is stored with heap organization with data unsorted with both respect to K and A, in pages of size D<sub>pag</sub>=1024 bytes each.

I have an array giving me the following costs for heap organizations (but actually for deletion it is **C<sub>s</sub>+1**).

[image]

---

According to my teacher the number of deleted records for an attribute operation is N<sub>rec</sub>(R)/L<sub>r</sub> = 100000/100 = 100. 
But I don't understand why.

Therfore the cost of the operation would be : 
N<sub>page</sub>+100.

Comment: What if there are indexes on the table? What if there is a delete cascade? What if the pages are not in memory? What about undo / redo?